# Pygame - move two objects while clicking and dragging one of them

Tags: python, class, pygame, draggable, rect

I must be able to move both: green and red (pair) by clicking and dragging one of them, while keeping their position relative to each other. I am not sure how to do it with the code I already have. Should I create another class for red rectangles or use Parent Child classes? Help greatly appreciated.

```
    import pygame as pg

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (33, 133, 33)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode((700, 500))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
cT = 140 # cycle time
cNum = 3 # cyle number

class Rectangle(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    def move(self, rel_x, rel_y):
        self.rect.move_ip(rel_x, rel_y)

    def collidepoint(self, pos):
       return self.rect.collidepoint(pos)

class Rect1():

    def __init__(self, color, width, height, x, y, all_sprites):

        self.height = height
        self.selected1 = False
        self.rect = pg.Rect((x, y, width, height))
        self.rectangles = []

        for z in range(0, cNum * cT, cT):
            rect = Rectangle(color, width, height, x, self.rect.y - z + cT)
            self.rectangles.append(rect)
            all_sprites.add(rect)

    def move(self, rel_x, rel_y):
        self.rect.move_ip(rel_x, rel_y)
        for r in self.rectangles:
            r.move(rel_x, rel_y)

    def collidepoint(self, pos):
        for r in self.rectangles:
           if r.rect.collidepoint(pos):
               return True

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.selected1 = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            self.selected1 = False
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.selected1 :
                self.move(0, event.rel[1])


class Connection():

    def __init__(self, rect_1, rect_2, vel):
        self.rect_1 = rect_1
        self.rect_2 = rect_2
        self.vel = vel

    def draw(self, screen):

        for r_1 in self.rect_1.rectangles:
            for r_2 in self.rect_2.rectangles:

                dist1 = r_2.rect.x - r_1.rect.x
                velocity = int(dist1 * self.vel)  # green wave angle

                A_start_x, A_start_y = r_1.rect.topright
                A_end_x, A_end_y = r_1.rect.bottomright

                B_start_x, B_start_y = r_2.rect.topleft
                B_end_x, B_end_y = r_2.rect.bottomleft


                if B_start_y < A_start_y - velocity and B_end_y > A_start_y - velocity:
                    start_pos = (A_start_x, A_start_y)
                    end_pos = (B_start_x, A_start_y - velocity) # minus 50
                    pg.draw.aaline(screen, GREEN, start_pos, end_pos, 1)

                if B_end_y > A_end_y - velocity and B_start_y < A_end_y - velocity:
                    start_pos = (A_end_x, A_end_y-1)
                    end_pos = (B_end_x, A_end_y - 1 - velocity) # minus 50
                    pg.draw.aaline(screen, RED, start_pos, end_pos, 1)

def main():
    pg.init()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()

    objects = [
        Rect1(GREEN, 10, 58, 55, 244, all_sprites ),
        Rect1(GREEN, 10, 111, 188, 226, all_sprites ),
        Rect1(RED, 10, 68, 69, 222, all_sprites),
        Rect1(RED, 10, 121, 211, 202, all_sprites),]
    conns = [
        Connection(objects[0], objects[1], 0.1),
        Connection(objects[2], objects[3], -0.1),]

    done = False
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

            for o in objects:
                o.handle_event(event)

        SCREEN.fill(WHITE)

        all_sprites.draw(SCREEN)

        for c in conns:
            c.draw(SCREEN)

        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
    pg.quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The desired behavior is a bit unclear. If you drag a short red rectangle, should the short green rectangle move as well? And the same for the long red and green rectangle pairs? Or a short paired with a long rect?

Comment: @skrx Yes, the short green rectangle and short red rectangle should move together and the same for the long red and long green. And these two pairs (of short and long rects) should move independently. Sorry for the ambiguity here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could associate the rectangles by storing a reference to the other rectangle as an attribute (e.g. `self.associated`) and then update the associated rects as well in the `handle_event` method: `self.associated.move(0, event.rel[1])`

```
class Rect1():

    def __init__(self, color, width, height, x, y, all_sprites, associated=None):
        self.associated = associated
        # Snip ...

    def handle_event(self, event):
        # Snip ...
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.selected1 :
                self.move(0, event.rel[1])
                self.associated.move(0, event.rel[1])

def main():
    # Snip ...
    green_short = Rect1(GREEN, 10, 58, 55, 244, all_sprites)
    red_short = Rect1(RED, 10, 68, 69, 222, all_sprites, green_short)
    green_short.associated = red_short

    green_long = Rect1(GREEN, 10, 111, 188, 226, all_sprites)
    red_long = Rect1(RED, 10, 121, 211, 202, all_sprites, green_long)
    green_long.associated = red_long

    objects = [green_short, green_long, red_short, red_long]
```

Comment: I get error :  'NoneType' object is not callable or 'Rect1' object is not callable

Comment: I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/157813/bartnick81s-project?tab=general) where you can show me the error.